# How to Restart Android Activity and still call onsaveinstancestate

Tags: android

I would like to know if there is a way to restart an activity from the same activity with

```
 finish();
 startActivity(getIntent());
```

and be able to call onSaveInstanceState to save data to be used on restart of the activity.
I guess onSaveInstanceState will not be called since finish() is being used.

If there is any other efficient method please let me know.

Thanks
Gokul

Comment: Put aside the "onSaveInstanceState", first i want to ask : what do you want to do by restarting your Activity?

Comment: Why would you want to restart your activity? Please say why and I can give you another solution. Restarting an activity can never be good.

Comment: I'm creating a navigation app with 2 activities. The first activity passes the start and destination positions to the second activity.The second activity uses the data to acquire guidance by making a http request. I would like to update the guidance(restart the second activity) when user deviates from the path but with a new starting point and not with the one from first activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling [`Activity#recreate()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#recreate()).